# SQL Server Installation in a 2 node cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I'm installing SQL Server 2014 in a cluster for the first time, and am running into an issue.

Environment:

- x2 Windows Server 2008 R2 - with a load balancer in front

Steps so far:

1. Have the IP's
2. Have the Service accounts
3. Fixed all validation errors network binding etc.

**Issue**

There is already a service that exists, set up by infrastructure team using the DNS name and IP address I need to use if I'm following the SQL Server Cluster installation wizard.

[image]

**Questions**

1. How can I install SQL Server on this already existing service?
2. Going through the installation wizard, do I need to take the existing server and IP offline(indicated by red arrows above) I need to use the name indicated under services and applications in the wizard, but it already exists. I have the same issue for the cluster configuration step the IP address is in use.

[image]

3. would it be easier to just delete the existing service and let the wizard recreate it for me?